# Find $24 \cot^2 x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose $x$ is in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and $\log_{24 \sin x} (24 \cos x) = \frac{3}{2}$. Find $24 \cot^2 x$.

From the given equation we have $24 \cos{x} = (24 \sin{x})^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and so $24\cot^2{x} = 24^2\sin{x}$. How do we continue?

Comment: apply $\log_{\sin}$ to $24\cot^{2}x$ and keep in mind that $\cot=\frac{\cos}{\sin}$.

Comment: @luli How does that help us solve the question?

Comment: Is it $192$....

Comment: @ArchisWelankar How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**A Solution**

Since
$$
(24\cos(x))^2=(24\sin(x))^3\tag{1}
$$
we have
$$
24\sin^3(x)+\sin^2(x)-1=0\tag{2}
$$
We can try the rational root theorem to get
$$
\sin(x)=\frac13\tag{2}
$$
Now use
$$
24\cot^2(x)=24^2\sin(x)=192\tag{4}
$$

---

**Uniqueness of the Solution**

Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(24u^3+u^2-1\right)=72u^2+2u$, the function $24u^3+u^2-1$ is increasing for $u\gt0$. This means there can only be one positive solution. Equation $(1)$ says that we need $\sin(x)\ge0$. Furthermore, the maximum of $24u^3+u^2-1$, for $u\le0$, is $-\frac{3887}{3888}$. Thus, there can be no negative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have $(24\cos x)^2 =(24\sin x)^3,\;$ or $\cos^2 x =24\sin^3 x.\;$
With $y=\sin x$ this gives the cubic $24y^3=1-y^2$ with the real solution
$y_1 = \frac{1}{3} \;$ or 
$$x=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \approx  0.3398369$$

Comment: How do you prove this is the only solution?

Comment: The OP needs to find $\cot^2x$

Comment: @user19405892 The other two solutions are complex. $y=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{23}i}{16}$

Comment: There is no task to prove that there is only one solution. Wolfram Alpha
says $24\cot(\arcsin(1/3))^2=192$